# Convert CSV to list tree

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, data-processing

I have a csv list of towns that contains the town,county,country.
I removed the headers for the sake of not having to do so in the coding.

Here is what I have:

```
    locations={}
class Location:
    def __init__(self,town,county,country):
        self.town = town
        self.county = county
        self.country = country
    def store(self):
        locations.update({self.county:self.country})


for line in open('town-county-country.csv','r'):
    line=line.strip()
    line=line.split(',')
    x = Location(line[0],line[1],line[2])
    x.store()
```

This saves it in the dictionary perfectly. but now for every country I want a dictionary with the country as the key and a list of counties as the value.

I considered a for loop to create the country lists and a nested for loop to add the counties but that would have to have if statements among other things to check if the key exists and just doesn't seem like to best way to accomplish this.

Does anyone know a better way?

Ideally the output would look like this:

```
counties = {
'AK': [
    'ALEUTIANS EAST',
    'ALEUTIANS WEST',
    'ANCHORAGE',
    'BETHEL',
    'BRISTOL BAY',
    'DENALI',
    'DILLINGHAM',
    'FAIRBANKS NORTH STAR',
    'HAINES',
    'HOONAH ANGOON',
    'JUNEAU',
    'KENAI PENINSULA',
    'KETCHIKAN GATEWAY',
    'KODIAK ISLAND',
    'LAKE AND PENINSULA',
    'MATANUSKA SUSITNA',
    'NOME',
    'NORTH SLOPE',
    'NORTHWEST ARCTIC',
    'PETERSBURG',
    'PRINCE OF WALES HYDER',
    'SITKA',
    'SKAGWAY',
    'SOUTHEAST FAIRBANKS',
    'VALDEZ CORDOVA',
    'WADE HAMPTON',
    'WRANGELL',
    'YAKUTAT',
    'YUKON KOYUKUK'
],
```

Here is a short sample of the file I am opening:

```
Ampthill,Bedfordshire,England
Arlesey,Bedfordshire,England
Bedford,Bedfordshire,England
Biggleswade,Bedfordshire,England
Dunstable,Bedfordshire,England
Flitwick,Bedfordshire,England
Houghton Regis,Bedfordshire,England
Kempston,Bedfordshire,England
Leighton Buzzard,Bedfordshire,England
Linslade,Bedfordshire,England
Luton,Bedfordshire,England
Potton,Bedfordshire,England
Sandy,Bedfordshire,England
Shefford,Bedfordshire,England
Stotfold,Bedfordshire,England
Wixams,Bedfordshire,England
Woburn,Bedfordshire,England
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the expected output? Also, I would take a look into using * and ** which serves 2 primary purposes, both of which may help you, but in particular * can be used to unpack lists. e.g. x = Location(*line). https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Comment: You can also combine your string functions. e.g. line.strip().split(',') fyi

Comment: I will definitely look into the * & ** and I had seen the combination once before but I completely forgot about that. Thank you for pointing it out. I am still really new to python and have taught myself everything I know about it from w3schools and google with a dash of youtube.

Comment: Are the county/country pairs being stored in another csv and then you are trying to create a separate dictionary (not Locations) to store the country/county data?

Comment: No, ultimately I want to save them in a .py file that is nothing more than a monster dictionary.

Comment: That sample output I sent is the opening of the file as it is right now. It has 57 keys and each key has a list value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229753/discussion-between-mr-mooo-cow-and-taux1c).

Comment: Why are you using a class to indirectly add items to an external dictionary? Does the class have any purpose beyond that shown? Also, add sample data for which input and output is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added test data to your example csv since it only had 1 county:

```
Ampthill,Bedfordshire,England
Reading,Berkshire,England
Aylesbury,Buckinghamshire,England
Munster,Cork,Ireland
```

---

```
import pandas as pd  # pandas is faster than csv library and less lines of code than just reading the raw file

counties = {}  # will contain final data
df = pd.read_csv('town-county-country.csv', header=None)  # you can leave headers in your file header=None will ignore them
countries = list(df.apply(set)[2])  # df[2] = country  # set removes duplicates but does not preserve order

# add each country to counties dictionary
for country in countries:
    counties.update({country: list(set(df[df[2].isin([country])][1]))})  # we use set again to remove duplicates on the county and use .isin to lookup country(df[2])

print(counties)
```

---

```
output: {'England': [['Buckinghamshire', 'Berkshire', 'Bedfordshire']], 'Ireland': [['Cork']]}
```

Also, like I said in your original code you can do:

```
line = line.strip().split(',')
x = Location(*line)
```